# Time Complexity of .add() in HashSet of Vectors in Java

Tags: java, time-complexity, hashset, treeset

I have two java HashSets, as below:

```java
HashSet<Integer> H1 = new HashSet<>();
HashSet<Vector> H2 = new HashSet<>();
```

As the number of elements in each HashSet grows larger(and assuming some of the elements are unique, some aren't), does the time complexity of adding elements for the second HashSet(*of vectors) change(relative to the second HashSet(*of integers))? Or does the fact that the HashSet contains Vectors not effect the time complexity?

I understand the time complexity of `.add()` the first HashSet is(in general) O(1), but could someone clarify for `H2`?

Also, if it were instead, say, a TreeSet of Vectors, how would the time complexity of `.add()` change from a TreeSet of ints in that case?

Comment: The time complexity of what operation? Also you imply that these 2 sets are related somehow, but you haven't said how. Please clarify your question.

Comment: A `TreeSet` is ~`O(log n)` for `#get`. A `HashSet` is ~`O(1)` for `#get`. This is regardless of the type of element, as in `HashSet` it will compare the `#hashCode` and then `#equals`, whereas `TreeSet` will compare on `#compareTo`.

Comment: @AndyTurner: that's not remotely true.  A HashSet is going to have to call equals, which takes linear time for Vectors.  (And hashCode will take linear time, too.). Linear in the length of the vectors, that is -- you now have to deal with the length of the vectors and the number of vectors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question makes some false assumptions

```
HashSet<Integer> H1 = new HashSet<>();
HashSet<Vector> H2 = new HashSet<>();
```

Vector is a legacy synchronized class from Java 1.0. You're probably better off using ArrayList. Vector is also a mutable class, meaning that it may not work properly in a HashSet if the Objects it contents are changing

> As the number of elements in each HashSet grows larger(and assuming
> some of the elements are unique, some aren't)

There cannot be non-unique elements in a Set

> As the number of elements in each HashSet grows larger(and assuming
> some of the elements are unique, some aren't), does the time
> complexity of adding elements for the second HashSet(*of vectors)
> change(relative to the second HashSet(*of integers))? Or does the fact
> that the HashSet contains Vectors not effect the time complexity?
>
> I understand the time complexity of .add() the first HashSet is(in
> general) O(1), but could someone clarify for H2?

Basically, larger lists will change the time complexity - not of the HashSet, but of hashcode() and equals. Also be aware that adding or removing elements from a List after it is added as a key in a hashmap / hashset will generally break the Map.

> Also, if it were instead, say, a TreeSet of Vectors, how would the
> time complexity of .add() change from a TreeSet of ints in that case?

You can't do this, as Vector does not implement `Comparable`